# Need quick Fix for captcha security flaw in EE 2.x

Tags: freemember, registration, captcha

1. On the registration form page, you take note of the captcha code and
   fill the form with errors (i.e.: unmatched passwords).
2. Reload the page , you now have a new captcha image.
3. Fill the form correctly (i.e.: matching passwords) and enter the
   old captcha code you got in step 1
4. submit the form

The form submits, while it should not. 
The security guys don't like that and I need a way to fix this.

Any ideas ?

---

Side note : I'm using freemember extension and reCaptcha extension does not seem to play nicely with free member. 
(the problem occurs even on default EE install)

Comment: I have same issue without any extensions and using channel:form. In my case the captcha field does not validating at all. You can submit the form with blank value for captcha.

Comment: Just posted what I did, it's a hack, but had no other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done is delete all existing captchas for current IP before creating new one. Drawbacks are minors, except it's a hack...

I post here as it might help others.

Around line 1530 in expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php

add following line

```
ee()->db->query("DELETE FROM exp_captcha WHERE ip_address = '".ee()->input->ip_address()."' OR date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-1200");
```

before

```
ee()->db->query("INSERT INTO exp_captcha (date, ip_address, word) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '".ee()->input->ip_address()."', '".ee()->db->escape_str($word)."')");
```